# Cannot save the row values after adding three new columns to existing jqgrid

Tags: jquery

I am using `jqGrid version 3.8.2`.I have created a `grid` with a `few columns`, in which the values of the previous row will be saved `on click` of any other row and the newly selected row will be in editable form, as a part of `editRow` and `onSelectRow` functionality.But, after adding 3 more columns to this grid, I am able to see the new columns in the grid, but now when I try to click on another row, the values of previous row will not be saved.Instead, both the rows will be in `editable format`.

Comment: please post your code also with the description

Comment: sorry,I am not supposed to share the code.If possible, can you please give some solutions.